# Conditional probability on Sheldon Ross Exercise 48

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> Sixty percent of the families in a certain community own their own car, thirty
>   percent own their own home, and twenty percent own both their own car and their
>   own home. If a family is randomly chosen, what is the probability that this family
>   owns a car or a house but not both?

I tried to solve this using conditional probability.

> Let A = owns car or home
>
> B = not both(car and home)
>
> then P(A|B) = ?
>
> P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B)
>
> P(A|B) = $\frac{P(B|A)*P(A)}{1-0.2}$

But i don't know how to get the value of $P(B|A)$. 
Is it the right way or i'm getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the randomly selected person need not belongs to $B$.

We are required to compute

$$P(A \cup B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A)+(B)-2P(A \cap B)$$